# How can I move an excel file using its own VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that I need to move from one folder to another at the click of the button. Currently I have the following code.

```
Private Sub btnReview_Click()
Dim FSO
Dim projectNumber As String
Dim fileSource As String
Dim fileDestination As String
projectNumber = Range("AI6").Value

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    fileSource = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name

    fileDestination = getProjectFolder(projectNumber)
    '        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    FSO.MoveFile fileSource, fileDestination
End Sub
```

Where `getProjectFolder` returns the path to the folder I want to move the file to(including the new name of the file).

This fails at the line `FSO.MoveFile` with error code 70, "Permission Denied". I am certain that this is because it isn't possible to move or rename a file while it is open. I have tried closing the folder before trying to move it, but that obviously ends the sub without executing any lines after the `ActiveWorkbooks.Close`.

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do *without* using some external file/code? I want the user to be able to push a button on a sheet, and then that sheet is moved to a separate folder. Is this possible? The only other ideas that I've had is to use the SaveAs method to save the file to the correct location and then delete the original file from the original folder. That seems to be a rather inelegant solution and I don't know how that would even be possible.

Any thoughts, tips, tricks, workarounds, etc. are appreciated.

Comment: do a save as and then delete the old?

Comment: You can make a copy of the current workbook at the destination. Moving a file, while it is  open isn't possible

Comment: @ScottCraner Any ideas how to get the file path of the old file in a nice way? I want to avoid hardcoded file paths as much as possible

Comment: To get the file's location, check `ThisWorkbook.Path` or `ThisWorkbook.FullName`

Comment: You would need to fire off an external process to perform the delete and then close the workbook. That way when the delete happens the file is no longer locked. This is easier said than done.

Comment: Could you share the `getProjectFolder` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Hiran Travassos's answer I shortened his code and made it more specific to the question.

```
Public Sub moveMyself()
    Dim oldFile As String
    Dim projectNumber As String
    oldFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    projectNumber = Range("AI6").Value

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs getProjectFolder(projectNumber), 52
    
    'Deleting the old file
    With New FileSystemObject
        .DeleteFile oldFile
    End With

End Sub
```

Also there is a trick you can use to continue executing code even after the original workbook that started the code got closed by abusing `Application.OnTime`, but it's a bit finicky.

Answer (score 2):

Easily done! Try as below, you can save it in a new folder and then proceed to delete the old file.

```
    Public Sub MoveMeToANewWorld()
        currentName = ThisWorkbook.Name,
        currentPathAndName = ThisWorkbook.FullName 
        currentPath = Replace(currentPathAndName, currentName, "")
        newPath = "NewFolder\"
        
    With ThisWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:= currentPath & newPath & currentName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    End with

'Deleting the OldFile
    With New FileSystemObject
        If .FileExists(currentPathAndName) Then
            .DeleteFile currentPathAndName 
        End If
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

Hope it helps you out!